Datetime picker in vuetify vuejs
We are using vuetify for our vuejs website.
We are able to integrate TimePicker and DatePicker in our project.
User has to click twice to choose datetime. Is there any way to choose both in a single click like DateTimePicker in other libraries?
For now, we are using v-text-field with type as datetime-local but we are looking for a better option.
<v-text-field class="mx-2" label="Choose" variant="underlined" type="datetime-local" v-model="datetime">


Can you programatically open the time picker when a date has been chosen?

that might be possible, but do they have any current component which fits with this ?

nah, vuetify datepicker is pretty basic - I use the DatePicker from v-calendar (though, I did have to fix some styling to make it look at least 90% like it belongs in vuetify theme)
